# Get REST API server response time in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get server response time in python 3

I have tried this code -

```
    api_url = "https://example.com?id=12345"
    api_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    api_response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_header)
    response_time = api_response.elapsed
    print(response_time)
```

But it is returning the "elapsed time" which is much higher than server response time.

When I query the same api from Postman, it shows response time of about 250ms.
But the above code shows the elapsed time of 850ms.

Is there any way to get the actual server response time in python 3?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `datetime` module. By storing the before and after times as variables, you can work out the difference between them, and thus work out the time taken to make the call.

```py
import datetime as dt


api_url = "https://example.com?id=12345"
api_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

start = dt.datetime.now()
api_response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_header)
end = dt.datetime.now()

time_delta = end - start
response_time = time_delta.total_seconds()

print(response_time)
```

If this doesn't do what you want, I suggest looking at the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: I think this is what elapsed does internally. I tried this, but it is giving similar response time as elapsed like 822ms vs 819ms. The elapsed time is even lesser by a few microseconds when compared to this method.